# make shared element on pages django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

Hello I want to know how to make element like in `soundcloud` or `spotify` when you play music there is that element that stay the same even when you change page[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SoundCloud and Spotify achieve this by having dynamic page loading, which means that they don't actually change page, but instead dynamically read in new content when the user tries to navigate.

This isn't really related to Django, since what you're asking how to change content of a page without navigating away from it. It's often called dynamic page change, and is achievable with [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) among other tools.